# __import__ on a directory/module is not returning all the files/sub-modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I've ran into a problem where I get an `AttributeError` while using `getattr()` on a module. The error reads something like this.

```
File "/some_app/some_module/some_file.py", line 6, in inline_import
    cls = getattr(cls, package)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fileThatIsInDirectory'
```

The thing is the file is actually there, but when I printed `__dict__.keys()` on the module, it was missing a fair few modules, including the module I am trying to get. The directory contains about 53 .py files at the moment yet only 24 are attributes on the module.

All the directories containing .py files contain an empty `__init__.py` file.

Here's an example of some of the problematic code.

```
def inline_import(class_path):
    package_path = class_path.split('.')
    cls = __import__(class_path.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
    package_path.pop(0)
    for package in package_path:
        cls = getattr(cls, package)
    return cls
```

You use it by passing the class path of the class you're importing, like `'module.file.ClassName'`.

I thought it may had something to do with whether or not a .pyc file is there or not, but that is not the issue.

Comment: what happens when you actually do a `from module.file import ClassName`?  does that work in the interpreter?

Comment: The file is imported without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to import a package to make all its modules available. Your `inline_import()` function might have been called with the last segment in the name being a module instead of a class e.g., `module.file` instead of `module.file.ClassName`.

To avoid confusion, delimit names that are inside a module using `:` e.g., `module.file:ClassName`. It will make it obvious which names should be imported without looking at the filesystem.